# MSSQL to MYSQL Migration: Collation equivalent for SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CPI_CI_AS

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database-migration, collation, amazon-aurora

I am migrating my database from MSSQL to Aurora (MYSQL 5.7). I want to know the Collation equivalent for SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CPI_CI_AS in MYSQL. The closest I could find using (SHOW COLLATION WHERE Charset = 'latin1';) was 'latin1_general_ci'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL does not have any `COLLATIONs` that are simultaneously "case insensitive" and "accent sensitive".

If you don't have any "accents" in your data, then the issue is moot.  In that case, `latin1_general_ci` is probably what you want.

Here is what I see in the version I am running:

```
mysql> SHOW COLLATION LIKE 'latin1%';
+-------------------+---------+----+---------+----------+---------+
| Collation         | Charset | Id | Default | Compiled | Sortlen |
+-------------------+---------+----+---------+----------+---------+
| latin1_german1_ci | latin1  |  5 |         | Yes      |       1 |
| latin1_swedish_ci | latin1  |  8 | Yes     | Yes      |       1 |
| latin1_danish_ci  | latin1  | 15 |         | Yes      |       1 |
| latin1_german2_ci | latin1  | 31 |         | Yes      |       2 |
| latin1_bin        | latin1  | 47 |         | Yes      |       1 |
| latin1_general_ci | latin1  | 48 |         | Yes      |       1 |
| latin1_general_cs | latin1  | 49 |         | Yes      |       1 |
| latin1_spanish_ci | latin1  | 94 |         | Yes      |       1 |
+-------------------+---------+----+---------+----------+---------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The non-'general' collations shuffle the accented letters a little due to nation preferences.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need both in my case. Is there any workaround for this ?

Comment: File a feature request (or up-vote an existing one) at bugs.mysql.com .